# Two DIVs on the same position - but do not overlap with further content

Tags: html, css

I have two DIVs that may (both) vary in their size. They need to start at the same (upper-left) position of a parental box element, but the height of this (outer) box should be the same as the larger of the inner elements.

When using absolute positioning (the common way to make elements overlap), the element that is positioned absolute, is taken out of the flow - and cannot influence the height of the outer box:

HTML sample:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Subsequent content
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.outer { position: relative }
div.outer div.inner1 { width: 200px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid green; position: absolute }
div.outer div.inner2 { width: 200px; height: 120px; background-color: yellow }

div.other { background-color: red }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L5qLrv4x/ - (I'd like to have the red DIV "other" below the larger of the two inner DIVs)

I'd like not to use JavaScript. Is there a CSS-only solution to have two elements (of variable height) at the same position **and** keep them in the flow to influence the surrounding content?

Thanks !

**Use Case**

Why shall someone need this? The respondent may paste a screenshot in my web application. Unless this has been pasted, a dummy DIV symbolizes where the screenshot may be pasted. This dummy is also `contenteditable="true"` to take the pasted content.

When the screenshot is pasted (which may have a different aspect ration than the dummy), it will be displayed in a DIV behind the (transparent) dummy. The dummy must stay on top to catch further paste events - new screenshots that may replace the one pasted first.

An additional form input is placed below this dummy+preview box. And of course, neither the dummy nor the screenshot shall overlap this input.

As my use case shows, JavaScript would be an option. My question for a CSS-only solution has two reasons: (a) Pure interest - I have learned that finding new solutions is often helpful in other situations, as well. (b) Less JS code that requires (additional) maintenance.

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/L5qLrv4x/2/

Comment: @RohitAzad this solution only works if `div` *a* is bigger than `div` *b* - if `div` *b* is bigger then the outcome will be different.

Comment: Basically, "No"...not without JS at some point. I confess, I'm unclear as to a use case here. Why would you have to content divs on top of each other? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Good point. I have added a description of my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a **trick**, **but** this solution is just for your question. **It's not generic at all.**

The trick is to move the second `div` "back" to the first div location.

```css
div.outer { 
  position: relative;
}

div.outer div.inner1 { 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 150px; 
  border: 1px solid green; 
  float:left;
}

div.outer div.inner2 { 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 120px; 
  background-color: yellow;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
  float:left;
}

div.outer div.inner2.higher {
  height:200px;
}

div.other { 
  background-color: red; 
}

.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h1>Div 1 is higher</h1>

<div class="outer cf">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Subsequent content
</div>

<hr />

<h1>Div 2 is higher</h1>

<div class="outer cf">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2 higher"></div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Subsequent content
</div>
```

Comment: Huh - interesting trick. I played around with `position: relative`, but did not come to float + transform. If the "other" element is `clear: both`, the workaround with a table-element becomes obsolete (http://jsfiddle.net/L5qLrv4x/5/). Inspiring, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want to achieve?

Here are the code:

**CSS:**

```
div.outer { position: relative }
div.outer div.inner1 { width: 200px; height: 150px; border: 1px solid green; position: absolute; display:block }
div.outer div.inner2 { width: 201px;height: 151px; background-color: yellow; display:block }

div.other { background-color: red; position:flex }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner1"></div>
  <div class="inner2"></div>
</div>
<div class="other">
  Subsequent content
</div>
```

**Jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/L5qLrv4x/6/

Comment: Actually, I'd like to have the "other" content below the two inner elements (irrelevant of their height). In this solution, the red box is within the "inner1" box.